# Understand swift Dictionary syntax

Tags: swift

I work with legacy code and i find following code:

```
let actions = [PrinterReportType.z: {
                        printer.printZReport($0)
                        DeviceFabric.lifehubTerminal().reconciliation()
                    }, .x: printer.printXReport, .openSession: printer.openSession}]
```

"Actions" is declared like this:

```
let actions: [PrinterReportsModel.PrinterReportType : ((String?) -> ()) -> ()]
```

Key is enum value, but i can't figure out what is value here.
I have new enum type of `PrinterReportsModel.PrinterReportType`, and i simply want to add new value to that dictionary. I suppose this is some kind of function. So, i want to declare that function, add it here, but i can't figure out how. And i can't figure out wha type is - `((String?) -> ()) -> ()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String` is a collection of characters.

`String?` means the same as `Optional<String>`, so it is either `Optional.none` or `Optional.some(String)`.

`(String?) -> ()` is a function that takes a `String?` and returns nothing (`()` also called `Void`, the zero-element tuple). Let's call this as a **`String?`-consumer**: it takes a `String?` and does *something* with it. Maybe it just throws the `String?` away. Maybe it prints it. Maybe it stores the `String?` in a variable or a database or sends it over the network.

You could define a `String?`-consumer closure like this:

```
let action: (String?) -> () = { (_ s: String?) -> () in
    print(s ?? "(none)")
}
```

(I'm fully specifying the types above, but you could omit some of the types and let the compiler infer them.)

You could define a `String?`-consumer function like this:

```
func test(_ s: String?) -> () { print(s ?? "(none)" }
```

And pass it around like this:

```
let action: (String?) -> () = test
```

You could define a `String?`-consumer method in a class (or struct) like this:

```
class MyObject {
    func test(_ s: String?) -> () { print(s ?? "(none)") }
}
```

And pass it around like this:

```
let myObject = MyObject()
let action: (String?) -> () = myObject.test
```

`((String?) -> ()) -> ()` is a function that takes a `String?`-consumer and returns nothing. You can think of this as a `String?`-consumer-consumer. Maybe it throws the `String?`-consumer away. Maybe it stores the `String?`-consumer in a variable for later. Maybe it calls the `String?`-consumer once, or ten times, or once for each element in some array of strings. Maybe it schedules a call to the `String?`-consumer every second until the program exits.

You could define a `String?`-consumer-consumer closure like this:

```
let action: ((String?) -> ()) -> () = { (_ sc: (String?) -> ()) -> () in
    sc("hello")
    sc(nil)
    sc("world")
}
```

You could call the closure like this:

```
action({ (_ s: String?) -> () in print(s ?? "(none)")}
```

Or like this:

```
let printString: (String?) -> () = { print($0) }
action(printString)
```

You could define a `String?`-consumer-consumer function like this:

```
func test(_ sc: (String?) -> ()) -> () {
    sc("hello")
    sc(nil)
    sc("world")
}
```

And pass it around like this:

```
let action: ((String?) -> ()) -> () = test
```

You could define a `String?`-consumer-consumer method in a class (or struct) like this:

```
class MyObject {
    func test(_ sc: (String?) -> ()) -> () {
        sc("hello")
        sc(nil)
        sc("world")
    }
}
```

And pass it around like this:

```
let myObject = MyObject()
let action: ((String?) -> ()) -> () = myObject.test
```

Comment: ok, thanks. But how can i 1) Declare that function 2) Pass it in parameter? I tried declare: func test(_ : String?) -> {} and add it like self.test(nil), but compiler didn't allow me to do that.

Comment: In your question, you said that `actions` is declared like `let actions: [PrinterReportsModel.PrinterReportType : ((String?) -> ()) -> ()]`. How do you know `actions` is declared like that? Is that what the documentation says? Or is that just what Xcode says when you option-click `actions`?

Comment: I've added some examples to my answer.

Comment: i click "actions" holding alt.

Comment: what exactly you mean writing - "consumer"? Or "consumer" closure?

Comment: “Consumer” is common English word: “a person or thing that eats or uses something”. [“*Closures* are self-contained blocks of functionality that can be passed around and used in your code.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID94) I understand that English is probably not your first language, but please make an effort to do your own research.

Comment: i do understand what consume means, but i don't understand how it relying to object of discossion. Please keep dialog constructive. If you follow:https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html
You will find not occurence of word "consuming"

Comment: It relates to this discussion because I gave the definition of `String?-consumer` in my answer: “Let's call this as a **`String?`-consumer**: it takes a `String?` and does *something* with it.” Thus a “`String?`-consumer closure” is a closure that is a `String?`-consumer, which is a closure that takes a `String?` and does *something* with it.

Comment: ok, thanks for your reply and definition then, that subject is kind of confusing for me :)